# Are "non-zero eigenspaces of a matrix" the same as "eigenspaces corresponding to non-zero eigenvalues"?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, terminology

Sorry for the long title. In essence, I'm wondering if non-zero eigenspaces are the same as eigenspaces corresponding to non-zero eigenvalues. That is, are non-zero eigenspaces = $E$<sub>$\lambda$</sub> for $\lambda$ $\neq$ $0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The former would be eigenspaces that are not the zero vector space, from the sounds of it.  But, in fact, eigenvectors are always restricted to being nonzero.

The eigenspace for eigenvalue zero would be another way of referring to the kernel.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! So a non-zero eigenspace is basically saying an eigenspace that isn't spanned by the zero vector (ie. an eigenspace corresponding to an eigenvalue).

Comment: Yes,  Zero of course always works.  But to be considered an eigenvector, the vector needs to be nonzero.  There are examples of eigenvalues with no eigenvectors.  For instance, in _defective_ matrices.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake.  All the eigenvalues have at least one eigenvector.  In light of which, the phrase "nonzero eigenspace" is a little redundant!

Comment: Now I think we should look at the context.  Axler may well have meant just to exclude the kernel.